# Split result into two columns and retain alphabetical order

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I've been struggling to figure out how to describe what I want to do (maybe that's why I can't find anything telling me how...). I'm also aware that my methods of doing things are kinda messy and aren't always most efficient, but I take the macgyver approach and it usually works out.

Basically, I have a table that I've been echoing as a list, with auto_incremented ids in the order the rows were inserted, and ordering alphabetically. The list is getting long and I want to split it into two columns while keeping it in alphabetical order

**Relevant code**:

```
    // grab tags from database excluding already associated tags
    echo "<ul id='taglist'>";

    $grabTags = "select * from alltags where t_id not in (select t_tid from tags where t_fid = '$fToDis') order by t_text";
    $runTags = mysqli_query($con, $grabTags);
    
    // echo tags
    while($hereTags = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runTags)){
        
        $tagIdRef = $hereTags['t_id'];
        $tagName = $hereTags['t_text'];
        
        echo "<li><div class='ellis'><div class='ell'><p>$tagName</p></div><div class='elr'><div class='bruhp'><form method='post'><input type='hidden' name='$tagIdRef'><input type='submit' class='howbout' value='Add to Film'></form></div></div></div></li>";
        
        // insert tag associations
        if(isset($_POST["$tagIdRef"])){
            
            $fTAddInit = "insert into tags (t_fid, t_tid) values ('$fToDis', '$tagIdRef')";
            $fTAddRun = mysqli_query($con, $fTAddInit);
            
            // refresh on success
            if($fTAddRun){
                
                echo "Tag added successfully, please hold while the page refreshes";
               
                echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1'>";
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
```

I have this javascript search filter on it

```
<div class='searchForms'>
  <input type='text' id='addtagto' onkeyup='jfunAddTag()' placeholder='Filter Existing Tags'>
</div>
```

```
<script>

  function jfunAddTag() {

    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById('addtagto');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("taglist");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
      txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
        
</script>
```

This is how it currently **outputs**:

```
"official" [Add to Film]
based on book [Add to Film]
boxing [Add to Film]
cold yeehaw [Add to Film]
dog [Add to Film]
emotional [Add to Film]
extreme sports [Add to Film]
gambling [Add to Film]
i disagree [Add to Film]
```

and so on

This is how I'd like to **change it to output**:

```
"official" [Add to Film] | based on book [Add to Film]
boxing [Add to Film] | cold yeehaw [Add to Film]
dog [Add to Film] | emotional [Add to Film]
extreme sports [Add to Film] | gambling [Add to Film]
i disagree [Add to Film]
```

And so on

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Your queries are insecure / vulnerable to injection attacks. Please read about prepared statements.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thank you!! I've never heard of prepared statements, but I've been looking for something similar for ages and couldn't get anything to work until now! (Time to overhaul the code of this whole project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One options is you could just create css rules for the code you're already producing.

```js
function jfunAddTag() {

  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById('addtagto');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("taglist");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#taglist {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

#taglist li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
}

#taglist li .ellis {
  margin: 2px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.bruhp {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class='searchForms'>
  <input type='text' id='addtagto' onkeyup='jfunAddTag()' placeholder='Filter Existing Tags'>
</div>
<ul id='taglist'>
  <li> 
    <div class='ellis'>
      <div class='ell'>
        <p>"official"</p>
      </div>
      <div class='elr'>
        <div class='bruhp'>
          <form method='post'><input type='hidden' name='n'><input type='submit' class='howbout' value='Add to Film'></form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class='ellis'>
      <div class='ell'>
        <p>based on the book</p>
      </div>
      <div class='elr'>
        <div class='bruhp'>
          <form method='post'><input type='hidden' name='n'><input type='submit' class='howbout' value='Add to Film'></form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class='ellis'>
      <div class='ell'>
        <p>boxing</p>
      </div>
      <div class='elr'>
        <div class='bruhp'>
          <form method='post'><input type='hidden' name='n'><input type='submit' class='howbout' value='Add to Film'></form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class='ellis'>
      <div class='ell'>
        <p>cold yeehaw</p>
      </div>
      <div class='elr'>
        <div class='bruhp'>
          <form method='post'><input type='hidden' name='n'><input type='submit' class='howbout' value='Add to Film'></form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class='ellis'>
      <div class='ell'>
        <p>dog</p>
      </div>
      <div class='elr'>
        <div class='bruhp'>
          <form method='post'><input type='hidden' name='n'><input type='submit' class='howbout' value='Add to Film'></form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'll admit I didn't think of trying a css approach, I was caught up in all the php I've been doing oops. I'll have to play with the numbers to get it looking decent, but using inline-block with the set width works like a charm! 

(The 'based on book' comes from the sql database that echoes all of the tags and everything in the<li> tags)

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch from an `ul` and `li` HTML to a `table` or `div` approach. Then while looping, you need to keep track that every 2 elements, you need to draw a new line.

Here's a simple refactor of your code with a `table` approach

The first line becomes

```php
echo "<table id='taglist'><tr>";
```

Then the loop becomes

```php
$count = 0;
while($hereTags = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runTags)){
    $tagIdRef = $hereTags['t_id'];
    $tagName = $hereTags['t_text'];
    // Every two lines, you start a new row
    if ($count % 2 == 0 && $count > 0) { 
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
    $count++;
    // Changed from li to td
    echo "<td><div class='ellis'><div class='ell'><p>$tagName</p></div><div class='elr'><div class='bruhp'><form method='post'><input type='hidden' name='$tagIdRef'><input type='submit' class='howbout' value='Add to Film'></form></div></div></div></td>";
```

And finally at the end of your `while` loop

```php
echo "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: This displayed exactly how I wanted it to, but it broke the javascript that I forgot to include initially (edited original post to include), I tried changing the ul and li in the js to table and td but that didn't work (admittedly, I suck at js)